# Returning json data with Typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js, typeahead

I've been happily using Typeahead with Bootstrap 2 for a while. Now it's time to upgrade.

Using Typeahead's [Prefetch method](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch), how would I be able to look up a particular json value and use other values in the same object as input values?

Here's how I achieved my purpose with the Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead Plugin:

```
$('.restaurant_name input').typeahead({
  source: function(typeahead, query) {
    var _this = this;
    return $.ajax({
      url: "/restaurants.json?q=" + query,
      success: function(data) { 
        return typeahead.process(data);
      }
    });
  },            
  onselect: function (obj) {
    if (obj.City != ''){
      $(".restaurant_city input").attr("value", obj.City);      
    }
    if (obj.State != ''){
      $(".hotel_state input").attr("value", obj.State);     
    }
    if (obj.Zip != ''){
      $(".hotel_zip input").attr("value", obj.Zip);     
    }
  },
  property: "LocationName1"
});
```

With Typeahead.js, I'm not getting so much as a peep. Any ideas why?

Here's a two entry snippet from my json file, "restaurants.json":

```
[{"LocationName1":"13 Monaghan","City":"New Orleans","State":"LA","Zip":"70116","ShortDescription":"Great deli sandwiches on historic Frenchmen St."},{"LocationName1":"7 on Fulton","City":"New Orleans","State":"LA","Zip":"70130","ShortDescription":"7 on Fulton, offers contemporary New Orleans cuisine with innovative dishes that are as eye-catching as they are delicious."}]
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why dont you just reuse the good old typeahead from bootstrap 2.3.x? It is about 300 lines of script and a little bit of CSS. Personally, I have given up using typehead.js. It is overcomplicated, you cannot reuse old code, it is hard even to get the demos to work, it is poorly maintained and there is currently 135 (!!) onsolved issues.

Comment: Good point. It might come to that. But users have complained about slow autocomplete loading, and everything else has been migrated to bootstrap 3. There is a nice [Bootstrap 3 Typeahead Pluging](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) that promises easy migration but the plugin also requires a Grunt installation. I'm a little too crunched on time to learn Grunt right now.

Comment: less is more .. I can make a github with the typeahead extract I am using, if it has any interest

Comment: I use typeahead on rather large datasets. Like 40.000 entries. My "trick" is to make a static json file for those large lookups, mostly to avoid constatly database calls. They will silently be cached on the client. Everytime the database changes, I just create a new json.

Comment: I would love to see any use of typeahead. My data sets are rather large too, and I'm also spitting them out to a json (though would love to just use a mySQL request). ... For this project, I think I'm going to create a bootstrap transition script that updates bootstrap 3 elements to work with bootstrap-typeahead's functions. .. At least it'll look pretty, even if it doesn't have the nice new stability of typeahead.js.. I can post that to github too if you want.

Comment: And [here's a typeahead plugin for bootstrap 3](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) .. but I would rather completely upgrade to twitter's typehead.js